# Getting button to show next iteration of loop from XML file

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, loops, button

Ok so here is what I'm trying to do. I have an XML file that contains 1000 classified Ad's for my employer and he is wanting to be able to have each ad show up one item at a time. I have the XML file loaded and can get it to post the first Ad but I have no idea how to get it to go to the next item in the loop or to go backwards which is were I am having the trouble. Here is the code for trying to go forward.

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    x= x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    break;
}

document.getElementById("classified").innerHTML =x;  

function forward() {
    var text ="";
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        x= x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        continue;
    }
    document.getElementById("classified").innerHTML = x;
}
```

So what I'm trying to get to happen is with a button click I can get the next ad to post and remove the first one presented with the forward button and get the backwards button to do the exact opposite

Comment: So you want to loop manually through 1000 ads via two buttons ?

Comment: Do you mean browser history buttons by forward/backward buttons or some `button`s located in your html?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your ad's descriptions in array and remember current index (the one was shown). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/U6DhL/).

Sample code. I'm assuming you have two buttons with ids back/forward somewhere on your page.

```
var fakeAds = Array.apply(null, new Array(1000)).map(function(_, i){
    return 'some random text ' + (i+1);
}), //replace with actual data
     idx = 0, //current index
     display = document.getElementById('display'), //where to show
     total = fakeAds.length; //total number of ads

function show() { //actually show ad at current idx.
    display.innerHTML = fakeAds[idx];        
}

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function(){
    --idx < 0 && (idx = total - 1); //decrement index and show
    show();
});

document.getElementById('forward').addEventListener('click', function(){
    idx = ++idx%total; //increment index and show
    show();
});

show(); //do show starting index.
```

Comment: Yes I have two buttons forwards and backwards

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two functions you need : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NQg6y/1/)

From your code, this is how to extract at first all the `item` from your XML file, and then via the loop you get each `description` from them. This will generate a list stored in your `x` var.

This creates a list of all item elements in your XML file *(this is the full method below)*

```
var connectXMLFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Define which file to open and send the request

```
connectXmlFile.open("GET","PathToYourXMLFile.xml", false);
connectXMLFile.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
connectXMLFile.send(null);
```

Get the response and all `item` elements

```
var xmlDoc = connectXMLFile.responseXML;
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

Represents the list of ads you got

```
var adsList = [];
```

Then loop to get each `description` and add it to the list

```
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
   adsList.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Represents the current ad showed

```
var adNumber = 0;

function forward() {
    if (adNumber >= adsList.length) adNumber = 0;
    document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML = adsList[adNumber];
    adNumber++;
}


function backwards() {
    if (adNumber == 0) adNumber = adsList.length;
    document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML = adsList[adNumber - 1];
    adNumber--;
}
```

This is based on the code you provided, if you need any explanation feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like how it is working however I am not sure how to convert the XML file that I have into a raid to be read by these functions.

Comment: I edited my post to show you how to get your list from the XML file.

Comment: Should I put the request code in the header of the document? Also the XML file is saved on the same server as the website.

Comment: Nope the request code must be in the javascript, it isn't a real request, just the javascript way to look in a file. Concerning your path to the XML, it's the classical way :)